# 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=8.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, identity

I get this error when code execution reaches the following statement in program.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
{
    opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    //opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    opts.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub;      
    opts.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
    opts.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<AppUser>>("custom").AddDefaultUI();
```

Also the IEmailSender is not found in the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;` namespace and it says it is forwarded to `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` and I installed this package.

But when I want to write `using Microsoft.Extensions.Identity` namespace, the Identity part is not available from intellisense.

So I have written this simple interface manually and compiled the project, But at the end I get this error when run the application.

So what is the solution to this? should I wait for the next preview? I use .Net 8 preview 7.

Comment: What's the version of your visual studio?it works well on myside

Answer (score 1):

I found your project file in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906841/typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-nullable)

```
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.10" />
```

please update your pacakges to the correct version

My Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BlazorApp1.Areas.Identity.Data;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlazorApp1ContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'BlazorApp1ContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BlazorApp1Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));



builder.Services.AddIdentity<BlazorApp1User, IdentityRole>(opts =>
{
    opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    //opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    opts.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub;
    opts.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
    opts.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<BlazorApp1Context>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<BlazorApp1User>>("custom")
.AddDefaultUI();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapRazorComponents<BlazorApp1.App>();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

My csproj file(make sure your packages are updated to the correct version):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />     
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23408.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It works well:

[image]

Check .net sdks/runtime:

[image]